# Format and Editing notes on left side of screen

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Any chance we could move the "How to Format" and "How to Edit" notes to the left column instead of the right? That way we can expand the textbox, to the right **and** down, giving us more space to see our text.

#### Before

[image: before]

#### After

[image: after]

Comment: Some images to help your case?

Comment: I added a couple images to describe it as best i can ^_^

Comment: Another option would be to give the `textarea` a higher `z-index`. You can expand the `textarea` when adding a comment, but not when editing or adding an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think what should happen is like what happens in the comment text area when it is expanded:

#### Before:

[image: before]

#### After:

[image: after]

We should make the sidebar move over as well:
[image: afterrrrr it all]

Comment: I'm ok with this too, I just don't like my textarea behind my sidebar :)