# Make textareas (vertically) resizable

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, editor

As noted in several question here on Meta, resizing a `textarea` horizontally used to break the pages layout:

- [Prevent the post text area from being obscured by the sidebar when resized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96143)
- [Format and Editing notes on left side of screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117427)
- [Post text-area Resize Issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117853/post-text-area-resize-issue)

The first is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) due to a recent change that adds

```
textarea{resize:none;}
```

to the global CSS files.

As a Chrome user, this breaks my user experience, since resizable textareas are something I am used to. Preventing this causes me to be stuck to a tiny textareas (especially for comments), which I find annoying.

So, I propose to change to current behavior (again) to one of the following:

1. Entirely remove the `resize` property and let each browser deal with this individually (so everybody gets what he's used to) and simply raise the textareas' `z-index` (to prevent breaking the page layout).
2. Change the current code to

   ```
   textarea{resize:vertical;}
   ```

   since vertical resizing did not break the page layout in the first place.

Option 1 is my personal favorite, but I'd be happy with either one.

Comment: You may have to just do what you want with a user-script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As I said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118644), there's a good reason that this defaults to "off" according to the standard, and we're enforcing this standard on our site. This wouldn't be necessary if Firefox and Chrome adhered to the standard.

I do however have no issue with enabling resizing on a case-by-case basis *in places were it doesn't cause issues*. I'll enable vertical resizing for the "add comment" text box; that's fine and doesn't create problems, and I can see why you find that useful.

But defaulting it to on is not going to happen.

Comment: Well, I had a bad feeling about a request to undo a very recent change... I can't say I understand why the standard is a reason to make the textareas non-resizable (I had read your other post before), but making the comment area resizable is a good compromise. It's where it is needed most.

Comment: @Dennis: The standard isn't the *reason*; my point is just that I agree with it -- this should default to off.

Comment: OK, now I got it.

Comment: Any chance the flagging, "it needs ♦ moderator attention", "other" can get the same love too?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is already [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) and resizable textareas is my third most important reason why you should totally drop that and try <s>jQuery</s> Chrome, I wrote a user script to re-enable vertical resizing.

You can view and install the script [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/2937/).

Comment: Nice! And I guess in time I will even enable such thing for all sites, not just the SE-family.