# Markdown help and preview for bounty text

Tags: feature-request, bounties, bounty-remarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Give some love to the Bounty tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133640/give-some-love-to-the-bounty-tool)

Given that [you can't edit bounty text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188/162730) after it's started, it would be helpful:

1. If there would be a **preview** of your bounty text, before posting it; and/or
2. If there would be a link to **view the available markdown** that's allowed, much like the help for comments.

---

If neither of those is possible, these related things might at least be helpful:

- Introduce a **warning about [newlines being removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124016/line-breaks-paragraphs-for-bounty-text)** from the bounty text. *Or*: change things so the input text area won't accept linebreaks anymore (since they will be stripped anyways).
- Allow for a [**short time frame for editing**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141588/162730) the bounty text.

---

The [allowed markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120346/162730) can be summarized in a mere paragraph, and may prevent others from being caught off-guard like me about [line breaks not being rendered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124016/line-breaks-paragraphs-for-bounty-text) in bounty text.

Reasonable request? Are there any other ways to help us get the best bounty-texts possible?

Comment: Come to think of it: perhaps a 5 minute time frame for editing the text would solve this problem as well, but that's maybe more an answer to the related question?

Comment: And why not, I've put up the "short editing time frame" suggestion as [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141588/162730) to the linked question.

Comment: isn't this request the same as [Give some love to the Bounty tool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133640/165773)? "...Add a preview, or an edit... or something? 3,000 chars is *a lot*. There is *a lot* of room for a typo or formatting error to slip in."

Comment: @gnat I hadn't seen that one yet. It has some overlap, but both questions do have something the other has not. However, I intentionally tried to make my question/request smaller / more specific / more concrete than "*give it some love*", hoping it may improve chances it would end up in a release.

Comment: @gnat Come to think of it, in terms of closing as a duplicate or merging the two, my post *may* also be suited as an *answer* to the other question? (Not sure if mods have the power to do that?) Let me know if I can do anything to help make things clearer, de-duplicate things, etc.

Comment: sure why not; if your question is closed as dupe, this would make an excellent opportunity to [meta-tag:bump] the target question. And by the way no need to bother mods; you can copy question text into answer yourself - for example I recently did just that when [my own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160288/165773 "here") was dupe-closed

Comment: Alright, I'll do that.