# Editing bounty messages, is it finally time for a little "Love"? (anti-Doh! feature request)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, bounty-remarks

I start [a lot of bounties](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/12102/uhoh?tab=bounties&sort=offered) and when I add a bounty remark I often get it right the first time. Once when a mistake in my message was problematic a moderator was kind enough to take the time to help me by cancelling/refunding it manually, followed by me starting a new one.

[This was proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141588/303080) in 2012:

> How about this:
>
> - a (say 5 minute?) **short time frame to edit** the text, much like comments
> - perhaps during that period a small warning for viewers, explaining the bounty text may still be tweaked
>
> That would allow honest folks to catch perhaps up to 95% of all minor (often formatting) mistakes, without a (big) risk of people investing wasted time to score a bounty while finding out later the bounty requirements changed a lot.

And in 2013, to the question [**Give some love** to the Bounty tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133640/303080), this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164888/303080) suggests (in part)

> I suggest, given that [you can't edit bounty text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188/162730) after it's started, it would be helpful:
>
> 1. If there would be a **preview** of your bounty text, before posting it; and/or
> 2. If there would be a link to **view the available markdown** that's allowed, much like the help for comments.

**Question:** In 2019, with all the improvements to the site in the intervening years, is it possible to reconsider some way to edit bounty remark **within 5 minutes** as comments have, or to have some way to correctly **preview them**?

I'm not sure if posting the draft message in an answer post window to preview will display everything correctly. There could potentially be typos or inadvertent formatting characters that display differently between the two, I don't know.

I also don't know if there are any bounty-scamming schemes that could be implemented by changing a bounty remark within the first five minutes, the danger seems low but unlike me, some people are clever...

---

Example of a non-critical formatting problem [from here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34099/12102); an extra space at the end of the [title ] results in a failed hyperlink display. Everyone can copy/paste it, but a functioning hyperlink would have been better.

[image: Doh! Typo in bounty message can not be fixed]

[image: Doh! Typo in bounty message can not be fixed]

Comment: Just for information: the related post [Can we have a way to edit bounty custom message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188/986753) is tagged (status-review).