# How do I find out how hot I am? Is there an easy-to-see user's total HNQ (total hotness) counter?

Tags: support, hot-questions

I noticed a that recently it seems that at least one of my questions have gone to the HNQ each week, though they are asked on different sites.

But I don't know how to verify this.

Is there a "total user hotness" function, something that shows how many of my questions have been HNQ this week or this month as a plot or numbers?

Comment: The answer is no. If you'd like this, you'll want this to be a FR. You might be able to get some info from SEDE but we don't track it anywhere... also, important to note that until February, we didn't track which questions hit the HNQ list at all, so the data won't go back very far. This could be a fun stat to track moving forward but it'd be pretty low priority, particularly if it's network-wide rather than single site.

Comment: @Catija Thanks, then I should learn how to use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE). I won't make a feature request. If I ever did, it would probably be for [a little "love"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324104/303080).

Comment: Sure. If you're lucky, someone may write it for you... Not quite sure why this is getting downvotes. Sorry about that.

Comment: I once wrote a query for that. Afaik you are the first or second.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1030066/users-whose-posts-got-most-times-hnq-ed-network-wide You are the record holder, network-wide!

Comment: @peterh yay, thanks! I do check this a few times a year for fun. It makes me happy in that it means people may be seeing questions and answers they might not otherwise see, and sometimes because of that joining more communities. I think "cross-pollination" between communities can be a good thing. *Thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh The company has cross-site stats, it is sure - for example, if you visit your [network-wide activity page](https://stackexchange.com/users/4794992/uhoh?tab=activity), that is coming from an aggregated db. Any idea, suggestion, etc. to make this site-aggregation more public, were ignored/rejected on the most crap reasons. Only the company knows, why are they doing it so, but I can not imagine any reason for them what would not be evil.

Comment: @uhoh SEDE can be tricked to create aggregated, network-wide queries, and this is what also I am doing, but it is big work (sites need to be iterated in a procedural SQL loop, collect the data induvidually, then merge and display the results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SE broke [peterh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259412/peterh)'s [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1030066/users-whose-posts-got-most-times-hnq-ed-network-wide) to see the HNQ count network-wide for all  users. I forked it and fixed: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1682302

```
CREATE TABLE #output (
  dbname VARCHAR(max),
  UserName NVARCHAR(40),
  SEAccountId INT,
  HnqCount INT
);

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE dbcursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sysdatabases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model' ,'msdb', 'Data.StackExchange','Worldbuilding_Temp','Meta_Temp','StackOverflow.Meta_Temp.dbo','Expatriates_Temp','StackExchange.Softwarerecs_Temp')
AND name NOT LIKE '%_Temp';

DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(max);

OPEN dbcursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @dbname;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT @query = '
    SELECT
      ''' + @dbname + ''' AS dbname,
      MIN(Users.DisplayName) AS UserName,
      Users.AccountId AS SEAccountId,
      COUNT(*) AS HnqCount
    FROM
      [' + @dbname + '].dbo.Users,
      [' + @dbname + '].dbo.Posts,
      [' + @dbname + '].dbo.PostHistory
    WHERE
      PostHistory.PostHistoryTypeId = 52
      AND
      PostHistory.PostId = Posts.Id
      AND
      Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
    GROUP BY Users.AccountId
    ';
  INSERT INTO #output EXEC (@query);
  FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @dbname;
END

CLOSE dbcursor;

WITH Raw AS (
  SELECT
    SUM(HnqCount) AS HnqCount,
    MIN(UserName) AS UserName,
    SEAccountId
  FROM #output
  GROUP BY SEAccountId
)
SELECT
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY HnqCount DESC) AS Rank,
  UserName,
  SEAccountId,
  HnqCount,
  'http://stackexchange.com/users/'
    + CAST(SEAccountId AS VARCHAR(30))
    + '?tab=accounts|' + UserName AS 'SE Profile',
  'https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/678540?AccountId='
    + CAST(SEAccountId AS VARCHAR(30)) + '#resultSets|' + UserName
    AS [With Hidden Accounts]
FROM Raw
ORDER BY HnqCount DESC, SEAccountId;
```

Answer (score 9):

We do not have any sort of counter for this anywhere on the network, not on a per-site or network wide basis... though that's not because it's not potentially interesting information. We didn't track whether a question was on the HNQ list until February 2019, so creating a feature like this wasn't possible until then.

That said, if we ever did create it, it'd be very incomplete as we can't create the data looking backwards before February. We just don't have the information. So, any tool would come with the giant asterisk "Data since February 2019".

If you are interested in the partial data you can probably do this in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) by requesting the count/site for the appropriate history event - I'm a bit sketchy on how such a query would work but there are some users here on MSE who are great with SEDE and may be able to help you with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A SEDE query would be just perfect for me, I'd just want to have a look from time to time, rather than the whole gamification experience.

Comment: @uhoh here you go: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1023391?accountid=4794992

Comment: That's cool! Thanks, @rene :D

Comment: @Catija what about a number for HNQs per site/per month (this months HNQ)?

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard It'd be a useless stat for 99.9999% of people on the network. All time is much better. The other thing, that I didn't really mention... is that we tend to look at things people can kinda control... the average question on the HNQ list... just happened to strike a chord. It's usually more of an accident than anything else.

Comment: @rene yipee! Thanks *very much* for the help. I think with such a nicely written and clear example I can finally learn to use SEDE too.

Comment: @rene sorry to bother you, there's some obvious point I'm missing. The query in [your link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1023391?accountid=4794992), as well as [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1030066/users-whose-posts-got-most-times-hnq-ed-network-wide) are still returning 30 HNQs though there have been a few more recently (e.g. [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35600/12102), [2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/209161/51174)) Can you just mention what I need to do to implement them with updated info? Thanks!

Comment: @rene I can't figure out where I would ask this as a proper and on-topic SE question, otherwise I would have done that instead.

Comment: @uhoh SEDE is updated once a week, on sunday. At least one of your examples only became hot 18 hours ago. They will showup in the query only after sunday morning. I'm often pingable in chat, for example [in the SEDE room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede)

Comment: @rene I've just asked [What does the StackExchange.Cstheory.Meta_Temp.dbo.posts error message mean in SEDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348368/303080)