# I'm getting an "Invalid object name 'StackExchange.Cstheory.Meta_Temp.dbo.posts'." when executing a cross-site query in SEDE

Tags: support, data-explorer, hot-questions

Vanity causes me to visit [this SEDE page](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1023391/all-hot-question-across-the-network-for-a-user?accountid=4794992) from time to time to check out how hot I am. Today I [felt like the evil queen in Cinderella](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqmIMvWnIV8) because I received bad news:

received both errors:

> Invalid object name 'StackExchange.Cstheory.Meta_Temp.dbo.posts'.
>
> Invalid object name 'StackExchange.Tex_Temp.dbo.posthistory'.

Is this a temporary or transient error, or is this now broken?

> [image: Invalid object name 'StackExchange.Cstheory.Meta_Temp.dbo.posts']

The query was originally linked in a comment below [How do I find out how hot I am? Is there an easy-to-see user's total HNQ (total hotness) counter?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326343/303080)

Comment: It's the same issue as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309917/whats-the-codegolf-temp-database-and-why-does-it-mess-up-my-query. As this is a new regression, not voting this as a duplicate.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog oh, today is Sunday, got it!

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog it's indeed strongly related; this time it's not a bug but a regular [tag:support] question. I expect this might happen again in the future, so we can use this as an original.

Answer (score 4):

@Sonic is right, I encountered this before: [What's the Codegolf_Temp database (and why does it mess up my query)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309917/295232). That was a real bug; the SEDE refresh was stuck that Sunday and it took a staff member to repair the situation.

This time it's running smoothly; @rene explains [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309919/295232) that it's part of the regular import process. You can check [this simple query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1242381/refresh-timestamp-for-each-stack-exchange-site-cache-buster) or a [more complex one by @rene](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc) (fill a random number for the seed/cache breaker parameters) how the import is progressing; as I'm writing this, those _Temp databases don't exist anymore but Stack Overflow is still being imported.

You can either

1. wait until the import is finished; I've set up a [weekly monitor](http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1236884/refresh-timestamp-for-each-stack-exchange-site) on a related query, and [last week](http://web.archive.org/web/20200517210023/https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1236884/refresh-timestamp-for-each-stack-exchange-site) the import finished at 10:20 UTC.
2. adjust the query so that it ignores _Temp databases. That is relatively easy (again, [@rene explains how to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309919/295232)), but the downside is that results are partially stale.

Comment: I have an improved SEDE query to check restore status: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc and I just ran it and this is its result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rdLx.png