# Should bare URLs to SE posts show up as links in bounty messages, the same way that they do in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, bounties, markdown, hyperlinks

From [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) to *How does the bounty system work?*

> #### Can I use Markdown formatting in the bounty remarks? Can I edit the remark?
>
> Bounty notices [support the Markdown mini format used for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/what-markdown-formatting-features-are-available-for-bounty-remarks), with the [addition of double line (paragraph) breaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124016/line-breaks-paragraphs-for-bounty-text/344273#344273).
>
> The following markup syntax features are allowed:
>
> ```
> _italic_ and **bold** text,
> inline `code in backticks`,
> and [basic links](http://example.com).
> ```
>
> You [cannot edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text) the remark, so validate carefully before saving

The answer to *[What markdown formatting features are available for Bounty remarks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/what-markdown-formatting-features-are-available-for-bounty-remarks)* includes:

> Bounty notices will support our Markdown mini format, **using the same format as we allow for comments.** The following will be allowed... (emphasis added)

So if I had done my homework I would have come away remembering only "using the same format as we allow for comments" and assumed that a bare URL would also work as a link, the same way it does in comments.
I wouldn't have seen that bare URLs work *differently* than they do in comments.

**Question:** At some point in time, either as part of an implementation of the [anti-*Doh* feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324104/editing-bounty-messages-is-it-finally-time-for-a-little-love-anti-doh-feat) or totally separately, might it be a good idea if the treatment of bare links were changed so that they work the same way that they do in comments and/or posts?

I'm thinking that from a non-programmer user's point of view, it's easier if bounty messages work *either* just like comments or just like posts as much as is possible, instead of having a third set of rules. But that's just me.

---

On *[Have any Apollo (or earlier) astronauts reported seeing Earth's aurora or related luminescent atmospheric effects?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/46617/have-any-apollo-or-earlier-astronauts-reported-seeing-earths-aurora-or-relate)*

[image: Example of a bounty message with a bare URL that doesn't show up]

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I think you edited a quoted example. I feel that isn't the right thing to do. If you feel the qoute isn't properly phrased please edit the original as well, as that is a CW answer.