# Why did my bullets fail to display as intended in my bounty message even they display properly temporarily sandboxed in an answer post?

Tags: support, bounties, markdown, bounty-remarks

[Editing bounty messages, is it finally time for a little "Love"? (anti-Doh! feature request)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324104/303080) discusses the possibility of having perhaps five minutes to edit bounty messages because we can not see how any intended formatting will actually display *until after the bounty is already posted.*

The only current remedy for a problem is for a moderator to refund and then start again, not a good solution for us chronic bountiers.

I used a temporary answer post to format a bounty message on [Was Queqiao in a halo or Lissajous orbit? Why do sources disagree?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45920/12102) in Space Exploration SE.

This is a small problem, but the two bullets at the end show nicely in my temporary sandboxing in an answer post, but fail in the bounty message display, and to my knowledge this may not be by-design.

**Question:** Why did my bullets fail to display as intended in my bounty message even they display properly temporarily sandboxed in an answer post?

---

#### Here is the text I pasted into the bounty:

> ```
> It's true that the difference is whether the in-plane and out-of-pane oscillations have the same period or not and "same" is potentially a problem if they are quite close, but from what I've seen most orbits associated with L1 and L2 are very clearly trying to be one or the other. DSCOVR  is a great example of a deliberate Lissajous orbit (and I have absolutely no idea why, see below) and almost all the others are obviously in well-meaning halo orbits. Perhaps some help can be found in: 
>
>  - [Where can I find access to information provided by CNSA and Chinese scientists and reputable science authors?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46916/12102) 
>
> See also 
>
>  - [Why is DSCOVR in a Lissajous orbit? Wouldn't a halo orbit completely avoid the Sun exclusion zone?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31504)
>  - [Do Lissajous orbits have stable/unstable manifolds?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30175) 
>
> Both are currently unanswered.
> ```

##### Which, when used in this question, produces:

> It's true that the difference is whether the in-plane and out-of-pane oscillations have the same period or not and "same" is potentially a problem if they are quite close, but from what I've seen most orbits associated with L1 and L2 are very clearly trying to be one or the other. DSCOVR  is a great example of a deliberate Lissajous orbit (and I have absolutely no idea why, see below) and almost all the others are obviously in well-meaning halo orbits. Perhaps some help can be found in:
>
> - [Where can I find access to information provided by CNSA and Chinese scientists and reputable science authors?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46916/12102)
>
> See also
>
> - [Why is DSCOVR in a Lissajous orbit? Wouldn't a halo orbit completely avoid the Sun exclusion zone?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31504)
> - [Do Lissajous orbits have stable/unstable manifolds?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30175)
>
> Both are currently unanswered.

---

#### Here is a screen shot of the results in the bounty message; the last two bullets didn't work.

[image: bouty message, last two bullets don't display properly]

Comment: Bullet points are not supported markdown for bounty messages. The linked duplicate explains what *is* available for bounty messages :)

Comment: @uhoh If you're interested, I've added what should be a way to get pseudo-bullet points into the [answer on the duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120346/271271). Admittedly, I haven't actually tested it in a bounty notice, but it should work, as it just uses Unicode characters for the formatting.

Comment: @Makyen *cool!* I'm an active bountier so I will try to remember to test it as soon as I can. Thanks for that, and for the great edit here. I'd never thought to ask "Is there any way to implement bullets in bounty messages, the usual way doesn't work?" Feel free to adjust the question and if it is reopened add an answer. I'll try to test this ASAP.