# Why don’t we see a preview of the bounty message?

Tags: feature-request, support, bounties, markdown-preview, bounty-remarks

I'm wondering why we don't see a preview of the bounty message.

In [one of my questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448729/finding-a-unique-and-finite-expected-value-for-almost-all-functions), if the bounty message was in the main post; the second link; i.e., [the  following](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9405217.pdf) would show only [the  following](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9405217.pdf), but in the bounty message the spacing between *following* and *]* prevents the second link from appearing as just [the  following](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9405217.pdf).

Is there a way to add a preview to the bounty message as to avoid mistakes? And if not, may we please have one?

Comment: Related: [Editing bounty messages, is it finally time for a little "Love"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324104/editing-bounty-messages-is-it-finally-time-for-a-little-love-anti-doh-feat) (Follow the links in that q)

Comment: Why? Because Stack Exchange never implemented this feature. To have it, better change this to a feature request and ask for the feature to be added. (And no, it does not mean in any way it will be ever done, but we can ask.)